# OKTA multi-factor Authentication + Java + RestAssured: /authorize API call directs me back to login page

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, rest-assured, okta

I'm trying to perform OKTA authentication via API calls to access one of the apps our company is using. I am able to successfully authenticate through a web browser, so I am attempting to reproduce the same series of API calls executed in the web browser within the RestAssured API in Java.

To do this, we need to invoke a call to {oktaURL}/oauth/v1/token, which takes several form parameters: client_id, redirect_uri, grant_type, code and code_verifier. By generating this token, we can use it to authorize all calls made in the app by adding a header named "Authorization" whose value is "Bearer {token}".

I have almost all of the parameters but I am attempting to generate the "code" parameter using another API call to {oktaURL}/oauth2/v1/authorize, after having successfully generated an "okta_key" parameter for this service through successful authentication. When the service call {oktaURL}/oauth2/v1/authorize runs in the browser, a response is returned whose "Location" header contains the "code" encoded within the URL:

`"{oktaURL}#code=KPgE5DqCNbmqcg4pec_n&state=RKIjvKP9H0X0SZ0TtxBLsEUn647HiPXalMlR65n0f3tgdeURLGobMFZ5Jagdfjxb"`

However, when I execute this same service call in RestAssured, I do NOT get this value and get this instead for the Location:

`{oktaLoginURL}?fromURI=%2Foauth2%2Fv1%2Fauthorize%2Fredirect%3Fokta_key%3Ds8hTa0bGWkg0aJftmalC2QJ2_ydaJT2-pJKLWnpW5SI`

It appears that the attempt to authorize is redirecting me to the login page. Is there any reason why this is happening?

Comment: what status code is returned when you make the cal using Rest Assured ?

Comment: 302. Which only says that the request has been redirected, but obviously not successfully.

Comment: and you're making a POST call ?

Comment: A GET call. I tried POST as well, but it yielded the same result.

Comment: Check if this [link](http://biercoff.com/why-rest-assured-doesnt-redirect-post-requests) helps

Comment: I've already set setAllowRedirects() to false, which means that the request will return a 302. By setting it to true I get a 200 status code instead, but the "location" header still doesn't have the above "code" I'm looking for. In both cases, I don't get the value "code" that I need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217174/discussion-between-richard-chen-and-wilfred-clement).

Comment: @RichardChen I came across this post because you said you successfully generated an "okta_key" parameter. For my team that's the missing piece of the puzzle. I'm wondering if you could explain how you did that?